# Missing required field in DaemonSet

Tags: kubernetes, cadvisor, daemonset

I'm trying to run Cadvisor on a Kubernetes cluster following this doc https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/

Contents of the yaml file below:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: kube-system
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: cadvisor
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    name: cadvisor
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: cadvisor
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: cadvisor
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: google/cadvisor:latest
        name: cadvisor
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
      restartPolicy: Always
status: {}
```

But when I try to deploy it :

```
kubectl apply -f cadvisor.daemonset.yaml
```

I get the output + error:

*error: error validating "cadvisor.daemonset.yaml": error validating data: [ValidationError(DaemonSet.status): missing required field "currentNumberScheduled" in io.k8s.api.apps.v1.DaemonSetStatus, ValidationError(DaemonSet.status): missing required field "numberMisscheduled" in io.k8s.api.apps.v1.DaemonSetStatus, ValidationError(DaemonSet.status): missing required field "desiredNumberScheduled" in io.k8s.api.apps.v1.DaemonSetStatus, ValidationError(DaemonSet.status): missing required field "numberReady" in io.k8s.api.apps.v1.DaemonSetStatus]; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false*

But there is no infos about these required fields in the documentation or anywhere on Google :(

Comment: Please try with `apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1`

Comment: I already tried it, but I get an error -> error: unable to recognize "cadvisor.daemonset.yaml": no matches for kind "DaemonSet" in version "extensions/v1beta1"

Comment: ``extensions/v1beta1`` has changed to ``apps/v1`` since kubernets 1.16, and now it requires new stuff. You can't use ``extensions/v1beta1``

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do not pass `status: {}` in the yaml when creating resources. That field is only for status information returned from the API server.

Comment: That was the problem ! Thank you